# How does a compiler string together addresses in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

How does a compiler know which nodes to point to next in a linked list since each node's next or previous can be anywhere in the heap. Can i attach a specific memory address say 0x00000001 to a pointer and bind it to that address?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean.

Comment: I was trying to say  "How does a compiler allocate addresses to pointers and how does it reference these pointers during runtime? Specifically the next and previous addresses in a singly linked list and doubly linked list specifically"

Comment: Since these addresses are not fragmented next to each other like the file system in an operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, can you bind a specific address to a pointer?

Yes. In fact, that is precisely the purpose of a pointer. Memory is addressed by numbers. The first byte is in the address 0, the next is 1 and so on. A pointer is essentially an object that stores a memory address, which is internally simply a number.

In following example, we store the address of the object `i` into a pointer:

```
int i;
int* ptr = &i;
```

> How does a compiler string together addresses in a linked list

A linked list node is simply a structure with a pointer to the next (and previous in case of doubly linked list) node. The address of the next node is stored in the pointer.

> how does the compiler allocate [...] these addresses during runtime?

In whatever way the language implemnetation chooses to allocate. The language does not specify "how" memory is allocated. The way will differ depending on the storage duration class of the object.

Typically in practice, the language implementation will ask the operating system to map some memory. Variables with automatic storage are stored in what is called the "call stack", and dynamic objects are stored in "free store". How either of these are implemented is outside the scope of my answer. I would suggest studying how operating systems and compilers are made. It's a wide topic.

> how does the compiler [...] reference these addresses during runtime?

It stores the address. There are CPU instructions for accessing memory at given address.

> Can I for example , bind 0x00000001 to node3?

I don't know what "node3" is, but you can point at the address 1 if you want to. There's not much you can do with the pointer unless there actually is an object at the address. There's no way of creating objects into unallocated memory, and there is no way of allocating memory from arbitrary address in standard C++.

Comment: how does the compiler allocate and reference these addresses during runtime?

Comment: Can I for example , bind 0x00000001 to node3?

Comment: @TarunKumar you can, but if there isn't a node at 0x00000001, you have undefined behaviour. That's probably the case there, because of a thing called alignment. A struct with a pointer and a `int` will (on a 32 bit system) have an alignment of 4. Any address that doesn't divide 4 exactly *can't* be a valid pointer to such a type.

Comment: @TarunKumar see the edit.

Comment: The compiler doesn't do anything during runtime.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But the compiler chooses (at compile time) what the program will do at runtime time.

Comment: @eerorika To some degree.